# How does a typical electromyography result report look like?

Tags: test-results

How does a typical electromyography result report look like?

I'm not asking for usual values: I simply wonder what kind of graphs or tables I should expect that summarizes the results observed during the electromyography.

If it depends on the muscles being tested, I am most interested in the upper limb muscle group, and especially the biceps, triceps, deltoid, brachioradialis, flexor carpi ulnaris, FDI, and APB.

---

I am asking the question as I'm going through the electronic medical record of a patient who got a nerve conduction study + electromyography, and I cannot see any data (tables/graphs/…) pertaining to the electromyography. The only information regarding the electromyography is a pithy 2-line text going through the results. I wonder whether the electronic medical record  is missing the electromyography results.

For example, for a nerve conduction study, a typical result reports would contain, for each location, the latency, the amplitude, the distance and the velocity in both table and graph form:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a sample format for NCS/EMG [here](https://www.aanem.org/getmedia/ac9a1ad8-238a-4fc8-b3e1-86049bab33bd/Newsletter_Report.pdf)

> The report template below
>   is based on the AANEM’s educational paper Reporting the
>   Results of Needle EMG and Nerve Conduction Studies. A report
>   template helps the EDX physician adhere to and document required
>   procedures —by checking them off a list. This process will help the
>   EDX physician complete a thorough analysis of the patient’s history,
>   physical, and EDX data that will improve diagnostic accuracy and
>   result in quality patient care. The template also will help laboratories
>   applying for the laboratory accreditation program meet the criteria
>   used to evaluate EDX reports. The template was developed listing
>   the key elements for a EDX standard report excluding F-wave,
>   H-reflex, and repetitive stimulation studies. Physicians are strongly
>   urged to utilize this template to improve their reports.